# NameError: name 'LEFT_BUTTON' is not defined-Autopy ERROR

Tags: python-3.x

```
import autopy
autopy.mouse.click(LEFT_BUTTON)
```

OUTPUT:

```
NameError: name 'LEFT_BUTTON' is not defined
```

so I have tried:

```
import autopy
autopy.mouse.click(button=LEFT_BUTTON)
```

OUTPUT:

```
NameError: name 'LEFT_BUTTON' is not defined
```

Comment: i have no idea about this pls help

Comment: Have you tried `autopy.LEFT_BUTTON`?

Comment: how autopy.LEFT_BUTTON.click() ?

Comment: `autopy.mouse.click(button=autopy.LEFT_BUTTON)`

Comment: AttributeError: module 'autopy' has no attribute 'LEFT_BUTTON'

Comment: What about `autopy.mouse.click('LEFT_BUTTON')`?

Comment: it not work!!!!

Comment: it raise TypeError

Answer (score 0):

`LEFT_BUTTON` is defined in `autopy.mouse`. Either import it:

```
import autopy
from autopy.mouse import LEFT_BUTTON
...
autopy.mouse.click(LEFT_BUTTON)
```

or reference it directly:

```
import autopy
...
autopy.mouse.click(autopy.mouse.LEFT_BUTTON)
```

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name 'LEFT_BUTTON' from 'autopy.mouse'

Comment: AttributeError: module 'autopy.mouse' has no attribute 'LEFT_BUTTON'